# Android CameraX: ImageCapture.takePicture callback is not being called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using CameraX's `PreviewView` in Compose:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
val previewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }
val imageCapture = remember { ImageCapture.Builder().build() }
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
    .build()

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        lifecycleOwner,
        cameraSelector,
        preview,
        imageCapture
    )

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
}

Box(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { previewView },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
    Button(
        onClick = {
            takePhoto(
                imageCapture = imageCapture,
                context = context,
                executor = executor,
                onCaptureSuccess = {
                    // ...    
                }
            )   
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "take photo")
    }
}

private suspend fun Context.getCameraProvider(): ProcessCameraProvider = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this).also { cameraProvider ->
        cameraProvider.addListener({
            continuation.resume(cameraProvider.get())
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
}
```

Now, the `takePhoto` function looks like this:

```
fun takePhoto(
    imageCapture: ImageCapture,
    executor: Executor,
    onCaptureSuccess: (ImageProxy) -> Unit
) {
    val onImageCapturedCallback = object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCaptureSuccess")
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)
            Log.d(TAG, "onError")
        }
    }
    imageCapture.takePicture(executor, onImageCapturedCallback)
}
```

The `PreviewView` displays as intended. However, when I click the button to invoke `ImageCapture.takePicture()` from the `takePhoto` function, there is no logging from the callback object.

There are no exceptions, the callback is not called.

What is going on here? And how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Seems to be related to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238368992).

Using an emulator with API level below 31 works.